# Task scheduler and PHP / MS SQL connection

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2008, windows-task-scheduler, mssql-jdbc

I've a PHP page that access MS SQL database ...the page is working just fine if I'm running it via browser ... the problem happens when I tried to make this page runs via Task Scheduler. The PHP scripts is working but can't establish a connection with the database.

I'm working on windows server 2008 ... PHP 5.4 (wamp) ... using PDO ... all the extensions and drivers are installed probably (as the PHP page works perfectly via browsers) ... but when I run the PHP page via my scheduled task from the Task Scheduler it through this exception (PDOException could not find driver) - I got that from the error log-

I don't know what cause this problem ... I just want the PHP page works the way it works on a browser

I found something weird when I check PDO::getAvailableDrivers() from browser I get this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => odbc
    [2] => sqlite
)
```

But when i run from the scheduled task I get this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
)
```

Why ODBC is not available??

Comment: have the task scheduler call something that opens the page like a browser, curl or wget or something

Comment: Maybe you should post the page source here

Comment: If you call the php-cli, make sure to pass the path to the php.ini you want to use and check the user you run the task as permission to access the extension folder.